# React - Passing focus functions to child components using refs

Tags: reactjs, react-ref, react-class-based-component

In my parent component constructor (class based), I add a ref for an input field by using:

```
this.usernameRef = React.createRef();
```

This works just fine in the parent component. For example, the following works fine:

```
 const username = this.usernameRef.current.value; // this works
```

I'm passing .focus() call to the ref into a child component like so:

```
<ChildComponent
    onClick={() => this.usernameRef.current.focus()}
/>
```

In my child component, it gets called with an onClick event:

```
<a href="#" onClick={onClick} />
```

While the app is running, when I click on that link, I get the following error:

```
e.usernameRef.current.focus is not a function
```

Should I be going about this a different way?

For what it's worth, the child component is function based.

Thanks

Comment: Something is off between the code you showed us and the error you are getting: `this.usernameRef.current.focus()` or `e.usernameRef.current.focus()`?

Answer (score 0):

In React we have to use `React.forwardRef`

In the example below, FancyButton uses React.forwardRef to obtain the ref passed to it, and then forward it to the DOM button that it renders:

```
const FancyButton = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (  <button ref={ref} className="FancyButton">    {props.children}
  </button>
));

// You can now get a ref directly to the DOM button:
const ref = React.createRef();
<FancyButton ref={ref}>Click me!</FancyButton>;
```

Comment: When I was trying that, I was getting "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'focus')"

Comment: Updated my answer, I use different approach

Comment: That's quite different from the original code and functionality. I don't think I can try a focus() this way.